# what does char** mean in a c program, can someone please give a correct explanation

Tags: c

what does char** mean in a c program, can someone please give a correct explanation.
I am looking at a function pointer related sort pointer and its a bit confusing.

```
  int compare(const void* a,const void* b)
 {
  char** sa=(char**)a;
  char** sb=(char**)b;
  return strcmp(*sa,*sb);
 }
```

Comment: Pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `C`, a `char**` means `pointer` to a `pointer` to a `character`.

---

```
char c;
```

means `c` is a character.

---

```
char *cptr;
```

means

```
1. `*cptr` is a character
2. `cptr` is a pointer to a characer
```

---

```
 char **pptr;
```

means

```
1. `**pptr` is a character
2. `*pptr` is a pointer to a character 
3. `pptr` is a pointer to a pointer to a character
```

---

In your case:

`char **sa` and `char **sb` are `pointer to pointer to characters`.

And, `*sa` and `*sb` are `pointer to characters`.

`strcmp` takes two `pointer to characters` as arguments, so you are passing those two `pointer to characters` when you are calling `strcmp` as:

```
strcmp(*sa, *sb)
```

---

Just, in case if you are confused how to call this function, you need to do something like this to call it.

```
/* Two strings */
char st1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
char st2[] = {'c', 'b', 'a', '\0'};

/* Call compare */
int ret;
ret = compare((void *) &st1, (void *) &st2);
/* Do something based on value of `ret' */
```

Answer (score 5):

Two asterisks designate a pointer to a pointer. Here is why you need it in a program that sorts strings:

Recall that C represents strings as arrays of characters. Each C string is typically represented as a pointer to character, i.e. `char*`, so an array of C strings is an array of `char*`.

C standard sort algorithm implementation uses comparison function that takes pointers to array elements. Since each element is a pointer, the function, therefore, takes a pointer to pointer.

The pointer to pointer passed to `compare` is wrapped in `void*`, which allows casting to and from any data pointer. The first thing the comparison function does is casting `void*` back to `char**`, so that it could *dereference* the two:

```
char** sa=(char**)a; // a is a char**, so we do the cast.
```

Now the string at the left-hand side is found at `*sa`, and the string on the right is at `*sb`. That is what we pass to `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, naive, explanation of `char**`:

```
char c = 'a';
char* p1 = &a;
char** p2 = &p2;
```

`p2` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

In an expression,

`*p2` evaluates to a `char*`.

`**p2` evaluates to a `char`.

However, there is more to it in the context of the function in your post. A "compare" function is used to sort objects. The standard library function [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) needs a function with same signature as your `compare` function to work correctly.

In your case, `compare` returns a value that can be used by `qsort` to sort an array of strings.

Given an array of strings such as:

```
char* strings[] = { ... }; // Initialize the strings
```

you can sort the strings by using

```
int numberOfStrings = ...;
qsort(strings, numberOfStrings, sizeof(*strings), compare);
```

`qsort` calls `compare` with the elements of `strings` by using a `void*` since `qsort` is agnostic of the type of data being held by the first argument. The only portable way it can call the compare function is by passing `void*`.

In the compare function, the user has to cast the pointers appropriately before making the comparisons.

When the compare function is expected to compare two strings, the `void*` needs to be cast to `char**` before calling `strcmp` on the dereferenced pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pointer to (pointer to char). Consider this

```
char c='x';
char *ptr=&c;
char **ptr2ptr=&ptr;
```

Simplifying :

```
c is char
ptr is char*
*ptr is a char
ptr2ptr is char**
*ptr2ptr is char*
**ptr2ptr is char
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a double pointer(pointer to pointer). `Double (**)`  is used to denote the double Pointer.

Double Pointer Stores the `address of the Pointer Variable`.

for ex.:

```
int num, *ptr1, **ptr2;
ptr1 = &num;
ptr2 = &ptr1;
```